# how to style the material-expansion panel from dart angular 2 material

Tags: css, angular, dart, angular2-material

[Image of material expansion panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CohZ.png)

Which css selector should I use to style the material expansion panel? The defauls header is white, but I want to change its color to blue.

```
<material-expansionpanel class="aaa" [expanded]="true" [showSaveCancel]="false" [disabled]="true" name="title">
     <div>
       Content
     </div>
</material-expansionpanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theming our components is not currently supported - there is a SASS-based API, but it's not yet exposed to end-users. It is on our priority list to make this available for users.

I've filed a meta tracking issue for you to follow:

https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2_components/issues/45

It's the holidays so I imagine we won't have much response until after the new years - feel free to hang out on our Gitter though - https://gitter.im/dart-lang/angular2.